# Write a modular C program that returns optimal number of coins for a chosen amount in a chosen currency

Tags: c, reusability

Write a modular solution (C program) that will accept as input an amount of money (in cents) in a certain currency and return the optimal number of coins in that currency.
The amount of money entered in is in cents and should be an integer value in the range of 1 to 95 inclusive.
The program should work as follows; First, it will ask the user to select a currency among the following three:

1. US$, which has four types of coins: 50, 25, 10 and 1 cents
2. AU$, which has four types of coins: 50, 20, 10 and 5 cents
3. Euro, which has four types of coins: 20, 10, 5 and 1 cents

It should ask the user to input an amount in cents as a number between 1 to 95 inclusive. If the chosen currency is AU$, your program should ensure that the input value is a multiples of 5.
Your program should then return the minimum number of coins (in the selected currency) that sum up into that number. For example, a poor solution for an input of 30 cents would give six 5 cent coins. A correct solution would give a 20 cent coin and a 10 cent coin.
After each output, the user should be asked whether they wish to continue (i.e., enter another amount) or exit/terminate the program.
Your solution (algorithm and program) should be designed using a modular approach.
**Important Note: For this problem, the principles of code reuse, low coupling and high cohesion, are particularly important.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "coins.h"

#define LEN 4   //Length of coin set.

void coin (int amount);

int main (void)
{
    int userSelection;
    int amount;
    int coinsUSD, CoinsAUD, CoinsEuro;
    char ch = 'y';
    
    printf("User to select 1 for USD, 2 for AUD or 3 for Euro: \n");  //User to select currency
        scanf("%d", &userSelection);
        
        if (userSelection == 1)    //User selected USD
        {
           printf("You have chosen USD\n");
        }
            
        if(userSelection == 2)  //User selected AUD
        {
           printf("You have chosen AUD\n");
        }   
                
        if(userSelection == 3)  //User selected Euro
        {
           printf("You have chosen Euro\n");
        }
         do 
            {   
           printf("User to select amount between 1-95 cents: \n"); //User to select amount between 1 - 95
        
         if(userSelection == 2) //If user selects AUD prompt for amount in multiples of 5
        {
            printf("If using AUD, amount must be in multiples of 5\n");
        }
            
            scanf("%d", &amount);
        
        while((userSelection == 2) && (amount % 5 != 0))  //If AUD amount is not a multiple of 5 
            
           {
            printf("Invalid amount, please select amount that is a multiple of 5: \n");
            scanf("%d", &amount);
           }
            
        while ((amount < 1)||(amount > 95)) //If amount is < 1 or > 95 give invalid message and prompt for correct amount 
          {
            printf("Invalid amount, please select amount between 1 - 95 only: \n");
            scanf("%d", &amount);
          }
            
          if (userSelection ==1)    //If currency selected is USD call USD function
          { 
            USD(amount);
          }
          if(userSelection ==2) //If currency selected is AUD call AUD function
          {
            AUD(amount);
          }
          if(userSelection ==3) //If currency selected is Euro call Euro function
          {
            Euro(amount);
          }             
        printf("Do you wish to continue with a new amount y=yes, n=no: \n");  //Ask user if they wish to continue with a new amount or terminate program
        scanf(" %c", &ch);
          } 
             while(ch == 'y');
    
}   
// This is the coins.c function
#include <stdio.h>
#include "coins.h"

#define LEN 4

void USD(int amount)
{   
    int i=0;//index of the array
    int number;//the number of least amount of coin for a specific coin value
    int coin_set[LEN]= {50, 25, 10, 1};//The USD coin set
    
    printf("The least amount of change needed for the amount of %d cents is below: \n", amount);
    
    while(i < LEN){
        
        if(coin_set[i] <= amount){
            number = amount/coin_set[i];
            
            //Prints the least number of coins needed
            if(coin_set[i] == 50 ){
                printf("%d x %d cents  \n", number, coin_set[i]);
            }
            if(coin_set[i] == 25 ){
                printf("%d x %d cents  \n", number, coin_set[i]);
            }
            if(coin_set[i] == 10 ){
                printf("%d x %d cents  \n", number, coin_set[i]);
            }
            if(coin_set[i] == 1 ){
                printf("%d x %d cents  \n", number, coin_set[i]);
            }
            
            amount = amount - number *coin_set[i];
        }
        
        i++;//increment i by 1
    }
}

void AUD(int amount)
{
    int i=0;//index of the array
    int number;//the number of least amount of coin for a specific coin value
    int coin_set[LEN]= {50, 20, 10, 5};//The AUD coin set
    
    printf("The least amount of change needed for the amount of %d cents is below: \n", amount);
    
    while(i < LEN){
        
        if(coin_set[i] <= amount){
            number = amount/coin_set[i];
            
            //Prints the least number of coins needed
            if(coin_set[i] == 50 ){
                printf("%d x %d cents  \n", number, coin_set[i]);
            }
            if(coin_set[i] == 20 ){
                printf("%d x %d cents  \n", number, coin_set[i]);
            }
            if(coin_set[i] == 10 ){
                printf("%d x %d cents  \n", number, coin_set[i]);
            }
            if(coin_set[i] == 5 ){
                printf("%d x %d cents  \n", number, coin_set[i]);
            }
            
            amount = amount - number *coin_set[i];
        }
        
        i++;//increment i by 1
    }
}

void Euro(int amount)
{   
    int i=0;//index of the array
    int number;//the number of least amount of coin for a specific coin value
    int coin_set[LEN]= {20, 10, 5, 1};//The Euro coin set
    
    printf("The least amount of change needed for the amount of %d cents is below: \n", amount);
    
    while(i < LEN){
        
        if(coin_set[i] <= amount){
            number = amount/coin_set[i];
            
            //Prints the least number of coins needed
            if(coin_set[i] == 20 ){
                printf("%d x %d cents  \n", number, coin_set[i]);
            }
            if(coin_set[i] == 10 ){
                printf("%d x %d cents  \n", number, coin_set[i]);
            }
            if(coin_set[i] == 5 ){
                printf("%d x %d cents  \n", number, coin_set[i]);
            }
            if(coin_set[i] == 1 ){
                printf("%d x %d cents  \n", number, coin_set[i]);
            }
            
            amount = amount - number *coin_set[i];
        }
        
        i++;//increment i by 1
    }
}
```

** This worked fine however my problem is I need the coins function of it to become more low coupling, high cohesion, Re Useable code eg:
const coins
coins = coin1 = 1
coin2 = 5
coin3 = 10
coin4 = 20
coin5 = 25
coin6 = 50
I'm just not sure how to implement this.

Comment: Never heard the American expression, "Don't take any wooden nickels." I'd suggest that the first thing you need to do is research the coin denominations available in each of those regions. You want to dispense up to 9 pennies in the US?

Comment: You can use an array of available coins for each currency. Consider using an array of `struct` that contains currency name, how many coins, the array of coin values, (another array of their common names), etc.

Comment: The first problem is "biggest coin first" doesn't always give you the minimum number of coins. For example, consider 34 cents in US$, where the "biggest first" algorithm gives you the answer "`1*25 + 9*1 = 10 coins`" but the best answer is "`3*10 + 4*1 = 7 coins`".

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define COIN_SET(currency_name, ...)                                  \
{                                                                     \
    .coin_values = (int[]){__VA_ARGS__},                              \
    .coin_values_size = (sizeof((int[]){__VA_ARGS__}) / sizeof(int)), \
    .name = currency_name,                                            \
}

typedef enum{
    FIRST = 0,
    USD = 0, 
    EUR, 
    AUD,
    LAST
}region;

typedef struct{
    int *coin_values;
    int coin_values_size;
    char *name;
}coin_set;



coin_set coin_sets[] = {
    [USD] = COIN_SET("USD", 50, 25, 10, 1),
    [EUR] = COIN_SET("EUR", 20, 10, 5, 1),
    [AUD] = COIN_SET("AU", 50, 20, 10, 5),
};

int get_min_coin(const coin_set *coin_set){
    //assume size >= 1 / coin_set has atleast one coin
    int min = coin_set->coin_values[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < coin_set->coin_values_size; i++){
        if(coin_set->coin_values[i] < min){
            min = coin_set->coin_values[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}

void get_optimal_coin_numbers(const coin_set *coin_set, int *coin_counts, const int amount){
    int amount_left = amount;
    for(int i = 0; i < coin_set->coin_values_size; i++){
        int count = amount_left / coin_set->coin_values[i];
        coin_counts[i] = count;
        amount_left = amount_left - (count * coin_set->coin_values[i]);
    }
}

int main(){
    int amount;
    int user_selection;
    char cont;

    // get required size for coin_counts array (max. number of coin types in a coin set)
    int size = coin_sets[0].coin_values_size;
    for(int i = 1; i < LAST; i++){
        if(coin_sets[i].coin_values_size > size){
            size = coin_sets[i].coin_values_size;
        }
    }
    // array to hold the optimal numbers of coins
    int *coin_counts = malloc(size * sizeof(int));

    do{
        // ask user to select a currency until a valid one is chosen
        do{
            // print all available options
            printf("User to select ");
            for(int i = FIRST; i < LAST - 1; i++){
                printf("%d for %s, ", i + 1, coin_sets[i].name);
            }
            printf("%d for %s: \n", LAST, coin_sets[LAST - 1].name);

            // get user input
            scanf("%d", &user_selection);
            user_selection--;
        }while(!(user_selection >= FIRST && user_selection < LAST)); 

        printf("You have chosen %s\n", coin_sets[user_selection].name);

        // get the coin set we need to use
        coin_set *set = &coin_sets[user_selection];

        int min = get_min_coin(set);

        // ask user to enter an amount until a valid one is entered
        do{
            printf("Enter amount (must be multiple of %d): \n", min);
            scanf("%d", &amount);
        }while(amount % min);

        get_optimal_coin_numbers(set, coin_counts, amount);

        // print out the optimal number of each coin
        printf("Optimal number of coins: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < set->coin_values_size - 1; i++){
            printf("%d %d-cent coins, ", coin_counts[i], set->coin_values[i]);
        }
        printf("%d %d-cent coins\n", coin_counts[set->coin_values_size - 1], set->coin_values[set->coin_values_size - 1]);

        printf("Continue (y/n)?\n");
        scanf(" %c", &cont);
    }while(cont == 'y');

    free(coin_counts);
    return 0;
}
```

The currencies only differ in their name, value of the coins (and potentially number of coins), the actual calculation for the optimal number of each coin is the same for all of them. The `coin_sets` array contains definitions for your currencies, you can easily add more currencies by adding a new entry to the `region` enum and to the `coin_sets` array, e.g.

```
...
AUD,
XYZ, // New entry for the XYZ currency in the enum
LAST
...

...
[XYZ] = COIN_SET("XYZ", 9, 3), // New coin set in the array with two coins with the values 9 and 3
...
```

Comment: Not bad, but there's a hardwired limit of 4 denominations with `int coin_counts[4];`... Aussie has $2, $1, too...

Comment: Tthank you for the idea above I will give it a try.   As for the he coin denominations these are theoretical only (i am an aussie myself), the question also calls for input amounts of no more than 95c which would in this case make the $1 and $2 unusable.

Comment: @Fe2O3 True, though you could just allocate an array large enough even for the coin set with the most coin types.

Comment: @Dragon Also note, that your algorithm doesn't give the minimum number of coins for all coin systems (but works for almost all real world ones). Look up the change-making problem.

Comment: Thanks @lulle2007200 I see what you mean appreciate your help